# Run a .jar file using .sh file in unix

Tags: java, bash, shell, unix, jar

I have a jar file `DirectoryScanner.jar` created in windows 7. I want to execute this jar on a unix server.
I ran the following command in putty and the jar run absolutely fine as expected:

```
java -jar DirectoryScanner.jar
```

Now I want to create a .sh file on the unix server which on executing can run this jar. I created a file Report.sh in which I wrote following code to execute this jar:

```
java -cp /home/applvis/Java/UAT/lib/DirectoryScanner.jar com.acc.directory.scanner.SDScanner
```

But when I execute this command in putty, it shows the following error:

```
[applvis@bg6lnxebs1 UAT]$ . ./ReportGen.sh
Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/acc/directory/scanner/SDScanner
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.acc.directory.scanner.SDScanner
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: com.acc.directory.scanner.SDScanner.  Program will exit.
```

Can anyone tell me what exactly I'm doing wrong, or suggest some alternate command.

Both my jar and sh file are in different directories. Even if they are in same directory, I get this error.

Ps. I have many jar files to be executed one after the other. So rather than again and again writing the command to run each jar separartely on unix, I want to create an sh file which will contain the code to run all the jars one after the other. And it will be easier for me to just run the sh file. Hence I need the code to be written in sh file which can run my jars.

Comment: why not sticking with java -jar DirectoryScanner.jar on unix?

Comment: Why is the command you put in the shell script different than the one you ran directly? Have you made sure that the SDScanner class is in that jar and that it has a main method?

Comment: I would suggest the most likely problem is that the path to the jar file is wrong. The Java -jar version would identify this whereas the class path would probably not.

Comment: the first command run absolutely fine so there cannot be any problem with jar. I am trying something new so that's why I want to write the command in a separate sh file.

Comment: I gave the same command in sh file but it still gave me the smae error

Comment: Make sure you haven't made type in class name (SDScanner) or package name (com.acc.directory.scanner). Also you can try use wildcard java -cp /home/applvis/Java/UAT/lib/* com.acc.directory.scanner.SDScanner

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your shell script change into the directory containing the jar files. Possibly not the best practice but I use this all the time to emulate a 'working directory' where scripts are started from. This way my shell script can be installed in a `scripts` directory and my Java can be installed in a `lib` directory.

Assuming your environment is the same when you execute the script as when you call the java from the command line.

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/applvis/Java/UAT/lib
java -jar DirectoryScanner.jar
```

Comment: Hello, yeah this worked, but what could be the main purpose of this ? I mean why should access to the directory then launch the jar ? the java -jar /home/..../file.jar doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Also if you'd like it to close terminal without terminating .jar process/program you can use this

```
 #!/bin/bash

__dir="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"

nohup java -jar ${__dir}/yourappname.jar > /dev/null &

exit $?
```

this line assigns current path of the bash file to __dir variable.

```
__dir="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"
```

so you can start jar , which is in the same folder.

here

```
nohup java -jar ${__dir}/yourappname.jar > /dev/null &
```

you write jar execution code between nohup and >dev/null &

Don't forget &. these will let you close terminal window without killing the process.

If you want to auto-close the terminal window you can use exit $?

If the process is successful $? executes exit protocol.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the tool you used to generate the JAR, it may have replaced your main class with something else that f.e. sets up the classpath and then calls your class. This happens a lot when generating fat JARs with all the dependencies. Do check the contents of the JAR, as it may contain other JARs in turn.

Comment: when I'm running the command java -jar DirectoryScanner.jar on unix, it is giving me the proper output. So I think the jar is fine, only thing is I need a command to be written in an sh file so that it can run that jar wherever it is present.

Comment: Extract the MANIFEST.MF from your JAR (a JAR is structurally a ZIP file) and see what main class is specified there. Is it your own? Also, Inspect the contents, are your classfiles in there?

Comment: Ya the jar is absolutely fine.