# How to run .jar file by double click on Windows 7

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

Running a .jar file in a command line works fine, but i am not able to run any .jar file by double clicking on my Windows 7 (64). It seems nothing happens after the double click

I set the path JRE path in my regedit HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT with JRE path but still its not running.

Any Solutions for this?

Comment: Yes but i need more clarification why this is not working normally?

Comment: If you read the answers given in that question that @AniketSahrawat linked, you'll see that there are suggestions on how to set up a file type correctly so that it always works with a double click without the need for a batch file (And explains why it is needed).

There's a whole host of explainations and suggestions on how to get it to work, even an app that will set it up for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `.jar` file called *Example.jar*, follow these steps:

1. Open a `notepad.exe`
2. Write : `java -jar Example.jar`
3. Save it with the extension `.bat`
4. Copy it to the directory which has the `.jar` file
5. Double click the `.bat` file which will run your `.jar` file

See [this article](http://java2career.com/2014/09/howw-to-write-batch-file-to-run-java.html) for a more detailed explanation of the above steps.

Comment: Thank you the answer it is working with windows. Do we have any other option make common for all operating systems?

Comment: You're welcome, if the answer is working please accept/upvote it :) 

For unix and linux you can run a shell script which is the batch file equivalent on unix based systems, note that the shell script is also platform specific, but should work on Unix and Linux based systems - please see this answer for how to make a .sh script for running a .jar (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847709/run-a-jar-file-using-sh-file-in-unix)