# Why opening a jar file thru ssh on a windows vm opens the browser incognito?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng, ui-automation

If I open manually (java -jar name.jar)it works. When I try to open it with ssh command it opens the browser incognito.
I have a windows vm with windows server. JDK is installed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine you have proper installation (your question details was little bit ambiguous) but in any case it could be the java command is not on the command search path for your user account and take this steps to make sure about installation

- verify that Java is installed `java -version`
- Confirm the PATH variable includes Java’s \bin directory in your remote machine

After verification create shell file and execute shell as `ssh user@host "sh ~/app-runner.sh"`, you may also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29847709/15758781) to how create shell for executing jar file(s).